from Refresh Token Not Being Applied in Subsequent Fetch Requests (Server-Side)
Issue Description
Working on a Next.js project where the server-side fetch requests need to handle token refresh when the accessToken expires. My server responds with a new accessToken in an httpOnly and secure cookie after refreshing the token. However, I am encountering an issue where the subsequent fetch request after the token refresh still uses the old cookies and doesn't include the newly refreshed accessToken.
Flow:

The app fetches user information on the server side.
When the accessToken expires, the API returns an error with the message ERR_TOKEN_EXPIRED, triggering the _handleError function.
Inside _handleError, I make a call to refresh the accessToken using this.request(apis.authn.refreshAccessToken, {}).
The refresh API successfully returns a 200 status code, and the new token is set as an httpOnly cookie.
However, when the original request is retried (after the refresh), it still uses the old cookies, and the new accessToken is not included in the request.

(Seem next/headers cookie is not autoupdated)
Using "next": "14.2.5"

  export class HttpClient {
  
    private _handleRequest = (req: RequestInit) => {
    if (!isBrowser()) {
      req.headers = {
        Cookie: require('next/headers').cookies().toString(),
      };
    }
  };
  
  async request(api: any, { data }: { data?: any}) {
    let url = api.url;
    let requestData = data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null;
    let requestInit: RequestInit = {
      credentials: 'include',
      method: api.method,
      body: requestData,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };

    this._handleRequest(requestInit);

    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${this.baseURL}${url}`, requestInit);
      return this._handleResponse(response);
    } catch (err) {
      return this._handleError(err, requestInit, url);
    }
  }

  protected async _handleError(
    err: any,
    originalRequest: RequestInit,
    url: string
  ) {
    if (err.status === 401) {
      try {
        const refreshResponse = await this.request(apis.authn.refreshAccessToken, {});
        if (refreshResponse.success) {

          return await fetch(`${this.baseURL}${url}`, originalRequest)
            .then(this._handleResponse)
            .then((originalResponse: any) => originalResponse.data);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
}


Hey, it's a bit hard to follow your code, but to me it seems like you're not applying Set-Cookie (with the new JWT) in the final response, so the brower receving the response won't update any stored cookies.

@NotX if u had read description there already set cookie on server-side so no need set-cookie at all. seem a problem here next/headers's cookie not autoupdate cookie on server side. but its work like a charm on client side

Ah, I misread. I thought the request succeeds and subsequent ones will fail - b/c this is likely to happen (too) b/c you did never add Set-Cookie to your final response. Regarding the question: I'm rather sure you cannot just invoke cookies() and hope it will take the right Cookie header from somewhere - it will probably use the incoming one for endpoint. Long story short: if refreshResponse bears the new JWT, read it and add it to the repeated request manually in the Cookie header before sending it. You can either do that manually or with https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies-next.

Also, I'ld ask you to mind your tone and drop phrases like "if u had read description". I read it, but it's quite contrieved and hardly a minimal reproducible example. Keep in mind: you're asking other ppl. to spend time to help you here.
